# Searching for multiple terms in a cell with AND-condition

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do a search for multiple strings in a cell with an AND-condition in Excel

---

E.g: I have a string `HNSP1` and I want to find some cells has  `HN and 1`

---

I'm using:
`=IF(SEARCH({"HN","1"},B3),600000,"")`

---

But the result is OR-condition
Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could just use an [AND](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) function along with [IsNumber](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/04/08/excel-isnumber-function-formula-examples/) and [Find](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628) to get what you need.

Try this in a cell reference `B3` and you should get a `true` result and then return the appropriate value

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("HN",B3),ISNUMBER(FIND("1",B3))),600000,"")
```

Comment: yes, Thank for your answer. It's worked! And  I edit my code `=IF(AND(SEARCH("HN",B3),SEARCH("1",B3)),600000,"")`